# MATLAB startup error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, matlab

I'm trying to run `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab` on Ubuntu 14.04, but on startup it gives me the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/databinding/ADBBean
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.mlwebservices.ControllingProductProvider.getControllingProducts(ControllingProductProvider.java:11)
    at com.mathworks.mlwebservices.DefaultActivationService.<init>(DefaultActivationService.java:34)
    at com.mathworks.activationclient.ActivationApplication.createActivationService(ActivationApplication.java:205)
    at com.mathworks.activationclient.ActivationApplication.<init>(ActivationApplication.java:194)
    at com.mathworks.activationclient.ActivationApplication.main(ActivationApplication.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

I'm not sure how to debug this problem. Any suggestions?

If it's applicable, I'm running `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, solved it. Turns out my MATLAB license was expired and it was trying to run the installation, which required root privileges, so sudo /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab allowed the installation to run correctly. Thanks!